# Construct a function that will be disjoint with continuum many lines

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory, transfinite-recursion, transfinite-induction

The symbol $\mathbb L$ will
stand for the family of all lines in the plane that are neither horizontal nor vertical. Also, we put $\mathbb L_0:=\{\ell\in\mathbb L\colon \ell(0)=0\}$

**lemma.**
Let $\mathcal F:=\{f_\eta\colon \eta<\mathfrak c\}$ be a family of distinct functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$ such all functions will be repeated continuum many times. Then there exists a function $h\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ such that for $f\in\mathcal F$ the family $$G_f:=\{\ell\in\mathbb L_0\colon (h+f)(x)\neq \ell(x) \, \text{for every nonzero}\, x\in\Bbb R\},$$ has a cardinality continuum.

**Proof.**
Let $\{x_{\eta}\colon \eta<\mathfrak c\}$ be an enumeration of the set of real numbers $\Bbb R$. By transfinite induction on $\eta<\mathfrak c$ we construct a sequence\
$\langle\langle h_\eta,D_\eta,\ell_\eta\rangle\,\colon\eta<\mathfrak c\rangle$ satisfying the following inductive
conditions for every $\eta<\mathfrak c$

(a)$D_\eta\in[\Bbb R]^{<\mathfrak c}$, $h_\eta\colon D_\eta\to\Bbb R$, and
$\ell_{\eta}\in\mathbb L_0;$

(b) $x_\eta\in D_\eta$,  $h_{\zeta}\subset h_{\eta}$ for every $\zeta\leq\eta;$

(c) $h_{\eta}(x)+f_{\zeta}(x)\neq \ell_{\zeta}(x)$ for all $\zeta<\eta$ and $x\in D_{\eta}\setminus D_\zeta$;

(d) $h_{\eta}(x)+f_{\eta}(x)\neq\ell_{\eta}(x)$ for every nonzero $x\in D_{\eta}.$

If such a sequence can be found, then
$h:=\bigcup_{\eta<\mathfrak c}h_\eta$
is as desired.  Indeed, $h\in\Bbb R^\Bbb R$  by (a), (b).  if
$\zeta<\mathfrak c$ is such that $f_\zeta=f,$
Indeed, for $x\in D_\zeta$ we have $(h+f)(x)=h_\zeta(x)+f_\zeta(x)\neq \ell_\zeta(x)$ is ensured by (f) used with $\eta=\zeta$.
At the same time, if $x\in \Bbb R\setminus D_\zeta$, then there exists an $\eta<\mathfrak c$ such that
$x\in D_{\eta}\setminus D_\zeta$ and the condition (d) implies that $(h+f)(x)=h_\eta(x)+f_\zeta(x)\neq \ell_\zeta(x)$. Since each $f$ will appear continuum many time so this shows $G_f$ has cardinality continuum.

My question is :

> Is the above argument mathematical correct?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @AlexKruckman, I edited the question. I was wondering if what I did is correct.

Comment: Are you intending that $h_\zeta$ is a proper subset of $h_\eta$ when $\zeta<\eta$? Since in (c), $x\in D_\eta\setminus D_\zeta$, I'm guessing that $\textrm{range}(h_\zeta)$ is a proper subset of $\textrm{range}(h_\eta)$.

Comment: @C7X, yes it is

Comment: @C7X, did you read the argument ?

Comment: @00GB Sorry, I didn't notice $\mathcal F$ was arbitrary and got bogged down trying to create an example pair $(\mathcal F,h)$. I'll need to finish reading the inductive argument for any $\mathcal F$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not real an answer I just want to say your solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

According to Gob your solution is correct, which I would agree with: it seems like if there were some $\zeta,\eta$ such that $f_\zeta+h_\eta$ is not disjoint from $\ell_\eta$ on its domain, we could pick an ordinal $\xi=\textrm{max}\{\zeta,\eta\}$ and consider the step in which $(h_\xi,D_\xi,\ell_\xi)$ is defined, contradicting the inductive definition.

Two things about this solution:

- How do we know that from each step of the inductive definition we can proceed without revising an earlier function (clause (b))?
- Additionally, I believe some parts can be simplified: for example, clause (d) in the $\alpha$th step of the induction is implied by clause (c) in the $\alpha+1$th step, since we may set $\eta=\zeta<\eta+1$, and $h_{\alpha+1}(x)=h_\alpha(x)$ for any $x$ in $h_\alpha$'s domain, we get $h_\alpha(x)+f_\alpha(x)=h_{\alpha+1}(x)+f_\alpha(x)\neq\ell_\alpha(x)$.